# Undefined reference to glewInit()@0

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

In MinGW I put `glew.h`, `glew.c`, and `wglew.h` into my source folder, then globally defined `GLEW_STATIC`. The problem is that right on the line of code `GLenum err = glewInit();` it tells me that there is an undefined reference to `glewInit()@0`. Why does it say that? I can't find anything online that explains a problem like this, since I'm using it properly.

Comment: Looks like you were compiling [tag:c] code as [tag:c++]. You might be missing an `extern "C"` somewhere.

Comment: It means there's a mismatch between the expected symbol name and the actual symbol name. glew32.dll compiled with msvc is decorated as `_glewInit@0`. glew32.dll compiled with mingw is decorated as `glewInit@0`. Note the calling convention being used is `__stdcall`.

Comment: @greatwolf: You are correct about the name decorations, but this is not for the DLL version of GLEW (`GLEW_STATIC` is used for the static linking version). The DLL version would generate an error along the lines of: `_imp_glewInit@0`. I am pretty sure this simply boils down to not correctly linking against `glew32s`.

Answer (score 1):

The GLEW library is not going to magically jump into your program. Did you include `glew.h` into your program? You're not telling that you did, you only mentioned, that you copied in the headers. Did you specify in the linker settings to link with the static GLEW library?